# Filter with 'or' in lodash shorthand expression

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js, filtering, lodash

Assuming I have a collection:

`var collection = [{type: 'a'}, {type: 'b'}, {type: 'c'}, {type: 'd'}]`

How can I filter it so only types 'a' and 'b' will remain? I would expect to do something like:

`_filter(collection, ['type', 'a', 'b'])`

I.e. use _.matchesProperty iteratee shorthand to handle multiple matching types, but it does not work that way. Do you know any simple way to achieve this, without defining a custom function?

Comment: What's so important about not creating your own function? `collection = _.filter(collection, function(e) { return e.type == 'a' || e.type == 'b' });` Done. Even better with ES2015: `collection = _.filter(collection, e => e.type == 'a' || e.type == 'b');`

Comment: It's not a blocker, but I was mostly surprised that this was not supported, and did some research to find nothing, so wanted to confirm this is actually not possible in lodash. 

Also, I'm playing with more functional way of doing stuff, so I was hoping someone would come up with an interesting use of _property, _.partial or something alike.

But you're perfectly right, this can be easily done with custom function, and even in elegant way in ES6.

Comment: You can consider using [conforms()](https://lodash.com/docs#conforms), where the `type` property uses [includes](https://lodash.com/docs#includes) that [binds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) `['a', 'b']` as its first parameter.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for, just added an answer with your suggestion. Thanks a million!

Comment: @ryeballar: Sounds like that would make a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great, to put ryeballar's suggestion into an answer:

Assuming I have a:

`var collection = [{type: 'a'}, {type: 'b'}, {type: 'c'}, {type: 'd'}]`

Below will filter out only 'a' and 'b' types:

`_.filter(collection, _.conforms({'type': _.partial(_.includes, ['a', 'b'])}))`

Not the prettiest code, but I think beats ES5 function and shows how _.conforms works. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: *"Not the prettiest code, but I think beats ES5 function..."* Um...eye of the beholder, I guess. I'd *much* rather see a simple `filter` call.

Comment: Well you're probably right, but it was an interesting puzzle nonetheless. :)

Comment: You say things like "shorthand expression" and "ES5 function" as if those have any meaning...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `_.filter` with a function to make it more functional, but simple `.filter` will also suffice:

**ES5:**

```
collection.filter(function (i) {
  return i.type === 'a' || i.type === 'b';
});
```

**ES6**

```
collection.filter(i => i.type === 'a' || i.type === 'b')
```

Comment: Thanks @naomik. I think when you downvote stackoverflow should ask for a reason. I don't understand why people downvote without even understanding the problem/ solution

Comment: I didn't down-vote this one, but I suppose it was down-voted cause I specifically excluded this solution in my question: "without defining a custom function"

Comment: @user633183 I may know why the downvote, and it's multiple reasons: 1. The question is tagged with lodash, and this answers does not use lodash's filter. 2. Lodash is mostly used for cross-browser compatibility. Filter is not compatible with IE11. 3. OP stated in a comment that he wanted to confirm that filtering with an or was possible in lodash or not.

I liked the answer, but in SO, we should aim to provide good answers with the context provided by the question, otherwise, it may not satisfy OP needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
collection.filter(i => ['a', 'b'].includes(i.type));
```